# Automate keyboard layout change in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout

I couldn't find the Belgian keyboard layout during Ubuntu 20.04 install, the option seems to be missing (some "belgien" layouts are listed, they're not what I need). The workaround is to execute the command `sudo setxkbmap be` at startup. Of course I'd like to automate this hassle.

I've tried putting the command (both directly and as a (tested) script) in crontab, preceded by `@reboot` through `sudo crontab -e`. The cron log lists this script so I suppose it has been executed, however, on startup the correct keyboard layout had not been loaded. I thought that perhaps it got overruled afterwards by system settings, but adding a minute of sleep did not work either. Neither does evoking `crontab -e` as regular user. Nor doing something like `@reboot root /path/to/script.sh`.

I've looked at anacron, but that one doesn't seem to be promising more control at startup either. I've also tried putting the script in `/etc/profile.d/`. This breaks the system. Using `~/.profile` appears not straightforward either for that matter, with reportedly inconsistent behavior.

Listing `bash /path/to/script.sh` in startup application preferences, too, is ineffective.

So do I really need to create a systemd service just for this? It seems like such a complicated ordeal for just changing the bloody keyboard layout..